# How to put bullets on every new line user enters in an EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText and I need to insert a bullet symbol every time when users switches to a new line.

An example output would be:

> *a
>   *b
>   *c

So far I have tried the following code: 
Now how can i append or concat bullet symboll for the new line

```
edtdescription.setOnKeyListener(this);

    @Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Listen to "Enter" key press
    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
    {

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information on what you already tried and where you failed. This will improve your chances to get an answer to your question. This is also why you are getting down votes. Here you will find more information on how to ask a question: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

If You want to create bullet list with editText structure.

I benefited this [reference.](https://gist.github.com/outlander24/771d8d6f0801cb6e9fabc1c03a9f5c5b)

You can use these [bullets.](https://fsymbols.com/signs/bullet-point/)

```
  EditText  edtNoteContent = findViewById(R.id.editText_description_note);            

  edtNoteContent.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter)
        {
            if (lengthAfter > lengthBefore) {
                if (text.toString().length() == 1) {
                    text = "◎ " + text;
                    edtNoteContent.setText(text);
                    edtNoteContent.setSelection(edtNoteContent.getText().length());
                }
                if (text.toString().endsWith("\n")) {
                    text = text.toString().replace("\n", "\n◎ ");
                    text = text.toString().replace("◎ ◎", "◎");
                    edtNoteContent.setText(text);
                    edtNoteContent.setSelection(edtNoteContent.getText().length());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Write More Here"       
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" /> 

 var bullet="A-"// any bullet symbol
 binding.etItem.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(e: Editable) {}
            override fun beforeTextChanged(
                arg0: CharSequence,
                arg1: Int,
                arg2: Int,
                arg3: Int,
            ) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(
                mText: CharSequence,
                start: Int,
                lengthBefore: Int,
                lengthAfter: Int,
            ) {
                var text = mText
                if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    if (lengthAfter > lengthBefore) {
                        if (text.toString().endsWith("\n")) {
                            binding.etItem.text.append("$bullet ")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to attach text watcher on the edit text and just check on each character update if you find a new line then add a bullet encoding string **"\u2022"** to your string. it will show as a bullet in edit text.

**textwatcher for finding new line**

```html
chatInputET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    String string = s.toString();
    if (string.length() > 0 && string.charAt(string.length() - 1) == '\n') {
      // concatenate your string with bullet here. 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i don't know how to concat string with bullet